# How do I add an image to the ''buttons'' on the header on my page?

Tags: header, shopify

Is there a way where I could change the normal plain buttons on the header like this one? (Image bellow) I have the debut theme and working on Shopify

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BAik.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your store css file and change class name where you want to apply image on button. Also you have to add  button image into your store  setting=> files

After that you have to copy image path and put into background-image ="change here image " in css code

```
<input type="submit" class="button">
button {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1023/3903/files/Capture12345.png?v=1652449658);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply add background:url('image-url') on button

```
   { 
    background: url('image-url');
    background-position: center;
    background-color: transparent;
   }
```